# Xcode 4 (final version) error when building

Tags: xcode4

I can't seem to find the answer.

I've just used Xcode 4 final version and built an existing project that was built ok with Xcode 3, but got this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem.B
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

But another project was built OK with Xcode 4.

I installed Xcode 4 by choosing the default options.

Do I miss to include a library or framework somewhere?

Could somebody please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's my solution for Xcode 4.0.2 with SDK 4.3 environment, but I believe it should also work on other setups.

1. `libSystem.B.dylib` is not present
   under
   `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib`,
   however it is present for lower SDK
   versions (e.g. `iPhoneOS4.2.sdk`)
2. most of the cases
   `libSystem.B.dylib` is just a
   symbolic link to `libSystem.dylib`
3. so in
   `iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib`
   I've applied following command `sudo
   ln -s libSystem.dylib
   libSystem.B.dylib` and my simulator
   builds started to work again :)

**NOTE:** `libSystem.B.dylib` is used by Flurry and Urban Airship so you better don't delete the reference in project file (of course Urban Airship does not work under Simulator, but I think Flurry does. `libSystem.B.dylib` may also be required by other libraries you included to your project.

**UPDATE:** solution still works for iOS5 Simulator after upgrading to Xcode 4.3

**UPDATE, March 9th, 2k12:** for Xcode installations via App Store, prefix above path with `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents` or the path where you've installed Xcode.app.

Comment: thank you for notifying this. Making the symbolic link works on me too. It could be a bug with the XCode version..

Comment: @Tanto: no problem, I just like SO community :) I think my solution is just a workaround that works rather than the real fix, which should be provided by Apple in next Xcode releases.

Comment: Still not fixed in iPhoneSimulator 5.0, but this fix worked for me.

Comment: The -weakl option (in XCode 4, this is an "Optional" link step) is needed to work on older devices, but breaks the sim. The above fix works for me, but is a glaring bug in XCode.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

Turns out that there was a reference to libSystemB in my project (Don't know why it's there). After deleting the reference, it built well.

Thanks anyway guys!

Answer (score 1):

> `-weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` breaks the iOS Simulator.
>   Use `-weak-lSystem` instead.

The quote belongs to gparker on the official dev forums.

Answer (score 1):

> -weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib breaks the iOS Simulator. Use -weak-lSystem instead.

nicktmro got it right， especially when you are developing cocos2d projects using xcode 4.x

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem since months and always kept making the symbolic link as described here everytime i updated xCode. Today I found a nice new way to fix this:

In your targets Build Phases go to 'Link Binary With Libraries' and search for:
libz.dylib

Set from 'Required' to 'Optional'

BUILD

BE HAPPY

Comment: can u also give me the solution for solving on device. because its working on simulator but not on device