# xcode 4 error: ld: library not found for -lSystem.B

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4, ios-simulator

Hi I am getting the following error ld: library not found for -lSystem.B, and I am not sure what to do to fix this.  I have tried other StackOverflow message steps to see if that resolved it but I still get it, and in fact doing some other changes gave me another error or two along with this one.  Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/MACOXIRIS/Documents/xCode Projects/barupay 1.3/Libraries/RestKit/Build/Debug-iphonesimulator'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/MACOXIRIS/Documents/xCode'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LProjects/barupay'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L1.3/Libraries/Build/Debug-iphonesimulator'
ld: library not found for -lSystem.B
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Ben

Comment: Does anyone have any idea of what I can to fix this?

Comment: For some reason I cannot comment on the original question, so I will have to post here. Would it be possible to show us the code that you have added since the last time you built the application and it compiled without this error? I'm not familiar with this error but perhaps if we look at the new code you added we can figure out whether you're missing an include, or framework, etc. I will edit this answer with any help I can provide if you can add more information.

Comment: The code I received worked on another person's machine but not working on my mini-mac...  Oddly the code itself has about 100+ files, and cannot share due to legal reasoning...  I have just never seen this error myself, if i we're to create a new project, and start from scratch I have no problem.  I also have no clue WHERE it is.  All the files compile I think it just that it is throwing it at the end of the compile. I''ll update my post above with a more accurate error, I guess what I showed was to simple...

Comment: I'm going off of the first 3 warnings here and taking a shot in the dark, is it possible that xcode does not have access to the project location for whatever reason? From how I understand the 3rd warning it cant see that part of the project which is probably where lSystem.B is located. This may also explain why migrating to another computer works. Is it possible that a directory reference in the new code is incorrect? I'm just thinking out loud for you here, I think you are right in that its nothing serious, just have to figure out how to fix it :P Keep us updated!

Comment: Okay thanks i'll do some more in depth search within the project files, and what not and see if I find a fix.  Thanks... And yes I'll keep everyone posted just in case someone does run into the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably fixed the issue long time ago, but whoever stumbles upon this issue, can have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6549418/344036). Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with GCC. It happened after I've replaced `Xcode.app` with `Xcode-beta.app`.

Run:

```
gcc -print-search-dirs
```

and you'll see where it looks for libraries by default. Move directories or create symlinks to make them available (another option is to recompile gcc).