# iphone app crashed with dlopen(/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib, 0x00000009)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk

iphone app crashed with `dlopen(/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib, 0x00000009)`

Console tells me that:

> SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib, 0x00000009).

When i link library libSystem.B.dylib, I receive error:

> ld: library not found for -lSystem.B
>   Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed >with exit code 1

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320788/xcode-4-final-version-error-when-building).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I specify the linker flag -weak-lSystem in Xcode build settings and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating the symlink from libSystem.B.dylib to libSystem.dylib or copying the lib into the iPhone Simulator folder from your `/usr/lib` directory.

To copy:

```
sudo cp -v /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/
```

Or, to create a symlink instead:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Now, run this to verify that the symlink is created or the copy was successful:

```
ls -l /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSys*
```

And you should see this if you used `cp`:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   107B Nov 21 19:08 libSystem.B.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   186K Sep 15 23:32 libSystem.dylib
```

Or, this if you used `ln`:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   107B Nov 21 19:08 libSystem.B.dylib -> /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   186K Sep 15 23:32 libSystem.dylib
```

---

Another idea:

If you recently upgraded to Xcode 4.2, there is a bug that causes projects to "lose" some of their frameworks (meaning they still show in the project, but Xcode doesn't actually know where to find them, and it doesn't get caught until run-time).  It is a fairly rare bug so this may not be what is causing your error, but it doesn't hurt to try out this fix.
Remove the `Celestial` framework from your project in both the 'Build Phases' and the file hierarchy:

[image: remove framework screenshot]

Then add it back to your project, do a 'Clean', 'Build', and 'Run' again.

Comment: I done this, but app stopped with dlopen(/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib, 0x00000009).

Comment: @Oksana Instead of a symlink, try copying it from `/usr/lib/` to the iPhone simulator path: `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/`.